# How to convert fetched records from database to tiff file in .net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, winforms, tiff

I have to create a windows application which will convert  fetched records from database(oracle , SQL Server ) table to tiff file in .net.

Please help with your kind suggestions !!

Comment: What exactly you want to convert? How? This is very high level task lacking any specifics.

Comment: If the byte array which you get from database is the bytes of a `.tiff` file you previously stored in db, then you can simply save it in a `.tiff` file again. You can do the same for all file types and it's not restricted to tiff files.

Comment: Actually, I need to know Base64 to tiff file in C#..